# Необходимо правильно извлечь данные из API JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Вопрос такой, мне необходимо получить из этого кода данные API, в консоль.log выводится то что мне нужно

```
return cc.coinList()
         .then((coinList) => {
              console.log(coinList);
              return coinList;      
          })
         .catch(console.error);
```

Тут в data() я получаю этот объект

```
coinLista : this.checkAllPrices()
```

но он выглядит из-за

```
return cc.coinList()
```

с лишними элементами пути

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как получить доступ к необходимой мне `Data` и правильно записать данные в `[[]]`?

Или еще лучше, как вернуть этот объект `coinList` в исходном виде?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Прочитайте про промисы и всё станет понятно. К свойствам в `[[]]` вы не имеете доступа, т. к. они внутренние.
Если вы хотите получить работающий код, то дайте пример на codepen, jsfiddle или codesanbox или, хотя бы, ссылку на документацию по вашему API.